Does a centripetal force cause an impulse?
Let's assume a  ball with mass $m$ is being twirled around on a string in a circular path at constant velocity $v$.
The centripetal force $F$ via the tension in the string is acting on the ball for time $t$.
Can I assume that there is an impulse  $J = Ft = ∆p$ acting on the ball?
If yes, why isn't there a $∆v$  change in the 'magnitude' of the ball velocity?
Or is using the above impulse-momentum equation not applicable for circular motion?

Remember that the impulse, momentum, and velocity are vector quantities, and that the impulse is the change in momentum, the vector, so it's not restricted to the change in magnitude. While $\Delta v$ is zero, $\Delta \vec v$ is not, as velocity changes direction.

Many thanks - yes I knew there is a change in the direction of the velocity vector but couldn't figure out  how to show the change in momentum mathematically using vectors. Other posters below have provided a variety of wonderful answers so many thanks again.

Do not forget to accept an answer if you find any of the provided answers satisfactory.

You may be forgetting that force and velocity are vector quantities. When a force is applied an object, it does not necessarily need to change the magnitude of its velocity. In your case for the uniform circular motion (circular motion with constant velocity), the NET FORCE acts perpendicular to the direction of velocity which will be towards the centre of the circle. This causes a change in the direction of velocity.
Impulse is defined as the change of momentum which will also be a vector quantity.
$\vec{J} = \vec{F}t = m\Delta{\vec{v}} = m(\vec{v_f} - \vec{v_i})$
$|\vec{J}| = m(\sqrt{|\vec{v_i}|^2 + |\vec{v_f}|^2 - 2|\vec{v_i}||\vec{v_f}|cos\theta}$
Where $\theta$ is the angle between the velocity vectors which will be the same as the angle subtended at the centre
In our case as velocity remains the same we have $|\vec{v_i}| = |\vec{v_f}| = v$
$|\vec{J}| = mv\sqrt{2 - 2cos\theta} = 2mv \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$
The change in direction of the velocity vector will result in a non-zero $\vec{J}$ although the magnitude of the velocity vector of the object will remain constant throughout
Also, impulse is as fundamental as force and force is defined using impose, hence where there exists force there will also exist an impulse

I got this image from this Physics StackExchange post on proof of formula for centripetal acceleration, you can also look at that post to clear any doubts relating to centripetal acceleration

Many thanks for this mathematical proof which I think is the easiest for me to understand.

So  is θ  180 degrees?

$\theta$ will be the angle subtended at the centre by the initial and final position vector from the centre. I will add a picture to clarify it in 1-2hr

Many thanks again.

My Pleasure....

The string provides a centripetal force which acts toward the center of the circular path.  That much is clear.  Whether you think of a "force" or an infinite series of  impulses is more of a thought experiment.  Most people would call it a force, not an impulse.
Velocity is a vector with both magnitude AND direction.  Either can change independently of the other.  Since the centripetal force acts perpendicular to the velocity, it changes the direction but not the magnitude of $V$.  That is the whole key to circular motion at constant rate.

Many thanks for your answer.

You are very welcome.

An impulse is an instantaneous change in the momentum of an object. As a whole, there is no change in angular momentum (assuming a constant velocity magnitude over time) for a ball orbiting a point via a string. From the perspective of either the anchor or the ball, one is orbiting the other, but from the perspective of the string they are both "orbiting" the string, each applying a constant and equal/opposite force to each other, so there is no force imbalance to result in a change in momentum.

I can understand there is no net force from the perspective of the string , but from the perspective of the anchor or ball , isn't there a force net centripetal force acting and therefore an impulse?  But yes, from the perspective of the string, it's a great explanation to show why there is no change in the magnitude of 'v'.

From the perspective of the anchor point, the entire universe revolves around it while it is stationary and the anchor is turning opposite the universe. Since the anchor is turning, and the universe is turning in the opposite direction to accommodate, there is no change in the direction of the force.

With a standard $m$ orbiting $r$ at $v$, lets consider a single orbit:
The period is:
$$ T = \frac{2\pi r} v $$
and the centripetal force is:
$$ F = \frac{mv^2} r $$
for a total impulse of:
$$ I \equiv FT = \frac{mv^2} r \frac{2\pi r} v = 2\pi mv $$
Now consider the particle's path in momentum space. In one period, it completes a circle with radius $p$. The total path length of that arc is:
$$ s = 2\pi p = 2\pi mv = I $$
So the impulse over a time $T$ is the arc length traversed in momentum space during the same time period.
The kinetic energy change at any time is:
$$ E(t) = \frac{p(t)^2}{2M}$$
and the rate of change of that is:
$$ \frac{dE}{dt} = \frac 1 {2M}\nabla_p(p^2)\cdot \frac{dp}{dt}$$
$$ \frac{dE}{dt} =\frac 1 {2M} 2\vec p \cdot \vec F $$
$$ \frac{dE}{dt} = \vec F \cdot \vec v $$
so to change the energy you need to change the radius in momentum space, and that requires work: force parallel to velocity.
Meanwhile forces perpendicular to velocity rotate the momentum vector, with the arc-length equal to the impulse.

Many thanks for providing a really elegant mathematical proof.
